# what does "is of importance" mean here?

Tags: sentence-construction, subordinate-clauses

> The “state of the system” is whatever standing stock ***is of importance*** — amount of water behind the dam, amount of harvestable wood in the forest, number of people in the population, amount of money in the bank, whatever.

It seems like there are two verbs (two 'is's) in this sentence. What is the grammar behind this? Is there anything omitted?

Comment: It's OK. Please note: This is not edited speech, and it is speech, as **whatever** is added at the end of sentences when people are talking. it's fine to say: **The pot on the stove is whatever pot is there when you enter the kitchen**. In written form, better would be: The "state of the system" is any significant amount of a material or stock in a system at a particular time: water behind a dam, etc. This sounds like an online answer to a student's question where the teacher wrote quickly.

Comment: To be of importance is poorly expressed English in this case. Something can be of importance but here a non-native speaker is probably using the idea from some Romance language where importance means significant amount of something.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct.  The structure is fundamentally a very simple "*noun-phrase* is *noun-phrase*" one:

**(The "state of the system") (is) (whatever standing stock is of importance).**

In the clause "whatever standing stock is of importance", **is of importance** basically means "is important" or "has importance".  [*Of* can be defined as "belonging to, relating to, or connected with (someone or something)"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of), so the standing stock is "relating to or connected with" being important.